# Python: Merge Sort in ascending and descending order

Tags: python, sorting, merge, mergesort

I'm trying to implement merge sort in Python that sorts either in ascending or in descending order depending on the parameter you give it. I got it working with 2 separate functions but I can't get it to work in one function.

```
def mergeSort(L, ascending = True):
    print('Mergesort, Parameter L:')
    print(L)
    result = []  
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L  
    mid = len(L) // 2  
    teilliste1 = mergeSort(L[:mid], ascending)  
    teilliste2 = mergeSort(L[mid:], ascending)  
    x, y = 0, 0
    while x < len(teilliste1) and y < len(teilliste2):
        if ascending:
            if teilliste1[x] > teilliste2[y]:
                result.append(teilliste2[y])
                y = y + 1
            else:
                result.append(teilliste1[x])
                x = x + 1
        else: 
            if teilliste1[x] < teilliste2[y]:
                result.append(teilliste2[y])
                y = y + 1
            else:
                result.append(teilliste1[x])
                x = x + 1
    result = result + teilliste1[x:]
    result = result + teilliste2[y:]
    return result

mergeSort(list, True) # sort in ascending order
mergeSort(list, False) # sort in descending order
```

Just flipping the > in the if-statement will make it descending but if I try doing both in one function, it always messes up my result. Any suggestions?

Comment: What did you try? It should not be hard, but it's easy to make mistakes, too.

Comment: To begin with, you should of course pass on the `ascending` parameter to the recursive calls.

Comment: I just put an "if ascending:" before the if/else part and an "else:" after and copied the whole thing with if teilliste1[x] < teilliste2[y]. 

It worked in 2 separate functions but here, it messes up the sorting of the second list.

Comment: Oh that fixes it! I must have completely missed it. Thanks! 

Still doesn't look very pretty with two if-statements nested. Is there a way to make it more readable? I'll update in the main post!

Comment: I think I would do `if (ascending and teilliste1[x] > teilliste2[y]) or (not ascending and teilliste1[x] < teilliste2[y]):` and then only one `else` clause is needed. If this is not a time-critical part, you could define a function for comparison, and then only have to mention the values once each.

Comment: I'm going with the first solution for now. If I still have time, I will try to implement a function. I have to do the same thing with quicksort in place for now, though. Thanks again, you've been a big help!

Answer (score 0):

```
def mergeSort(L, ascending = True):
    result = []  
    if len(L) == 1:
        return L  
    mid = len(L) // 2

    teilliste1 = mergeSort(L[:mid])

    teilliste2 = mergeSort(L[mid:])

    x, y = 0, 0
    while x < len(teilliste1) and y < len(teilliste2):
        if teilliste1[x] > teilliste2[y]: # < for descending
            result.append(teilliste2[y])
            y = y + 1

        else:
            result.append(teilliste1[x])
            x = x + 1


    result = result + teilliste1[x:]

    result = result + teilliste2[y:]
    if ascending == True :
        return result
    else:
        result.reverse()
        return result

list=[3,2,4,1,5,9,7,6]
print(list)
print(mergeSort(list, True) )# sort in ascending order
```